# Блоки не центрируются. В чем ошибка?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}




.container {
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;   
}



.promo {
    height: 800px;
    background: url('../img/bg/hands.png') center center/cover no-repeat;
    padding: 39px 0 62px 0; 
}

.logo .logo_img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.logo .logo_text {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 14px;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 53px;
}
.title {
    color: #f9bf3b;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 41px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

h2.title {
    margin-top: 21px;

}



.simple .title_big {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 21px;
}

.promo .promo_text {
    padding: 0 13px; 
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Light';
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 23px;
}

.promo .promo_text span {
    color: #f9bf3b;
    font-family: "Roboto - Bold";
    font-weight: 700;
}

.promo .promo_btn {
   display: block;
   margin: 73px auto; 
   width: 313px;
   height: 72px;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
   border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
   background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #2798b9 0%, #3ab6da 100%);
   text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
   color: #ffffff;
   font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
   font-size: 21px;
   font-weight: 400;
   line-height: 24px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   cursor: pointer;
   outline: none;
}

.more {
    margin-top: 73px;
}

.more .more_text {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Roboto - Thin";
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

.more .more_img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 13px;
}

.waiting {
    
    height: 604px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding: 85px 0 75px 0;
     
}

.waiting .waiting_header {
    color: #252525;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}

.waiting .waiting_divider {
    width: 217px;
    height: 4px;
    background-color: #f9bf3b;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    margin-top: 18px;
}

.waiting .waiting_subheader {
    margin-top: 17px;
    color: #4a4a4a;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}

.waiting .waiting_wrapper {
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.waiting .waiting_wrapper .waiting_item {
    display: inline-block; /* 3 блока класса waiting_item не центрируются: прилипли
    к левому краю*/
    
    width: 339px; 
  

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wordpress интенсив</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <section class="promo">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="logo">
               <img src="icons/logo.png" alt="" class="logo_img">
               <div class="logo_text">Wordpress Интенсив</div>
           </div>

            <h1 class="title">Создать свой сайт на Wordpress</h1>
            <div class="simple">
                <h2 class="title_big">Это просто!</h2>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <h2 class="title">Куда сложнее сделать это правильно!</h2>
            <div class="promo_text">Ежедневно в России появляется более 5 000 новых сайтов.<br>
                И только единицы из них становятся популярными и приносят ощутимую прибыль. В чем секрет? В чем формула успеха? Узнайте на предстоящем двухдневном <span>БЕСПЛАТНОМ</span> интенсиве!</div>
                <button class="promo_btn">
                    Записаться на интенсив!
                </button>
                <div class="more">
                <div class="more_text">узнать больше об интенсиве</div>
                <img src="icons/arrow.png" alt="" class="more_img">
                </div>
       </div>
    </section>

    <section class="waiting">
        <div class="container"></div>
        <h2 class="waiting_header">Что вас ждет в нашем интенсиве?</h2>
        <div class="waiting_divider"></div>
        <div class="waiting_subheader">2 бесплатных полноценных обучающих вебинара, где:</div>

        <div class="waiting_wrapper">
            <div class="waiting_item">
                <img src="img/pages.png" alt="" class="waiting_img">
                <div class="waiting descr">Всего за два бесплатных вебинара мы научим вас, как создать свой сайт на WordPress. </div>
            </div>
            <div class="waiting_item">
                <img src="img/board.png" alt="" class="waiting_img">
                <div class="waiting descr">Покажем, как правильно оптимизировать сайт и сделать его привлекательным для поисковых систем. Только свежая, профессиональная и 
                    актуальная информация!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="waiting_item">
                <img src="img/chart.png" alt="" class="waiting_img">
                <div class="waiting descr">Вы узнаете, что такое «хорошая индексация»,
                    «высокая посещаемость», «стабильный прирост посетителей», «ТОП по запросам» и, что намного важнее, как добиться всех этих показателей!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 3 блока класса waiting_item не центрируются: прилипли к левому краю

Comment: Например, убрать inline-block... дать их родителю display: flex и искать, как центрировать элементы flex)

Comment: Странно, в видео уроке все было ок, у меня не вышло. Перепроверила несколько раз. Где-то накосячила.

Comment: Автор центрировал элементы без flex

Comment: ну как показывает мой личный опыт, у себя не всегда работает так же, как у авторов видеоуроков или соседей))